# Is there a way to retrieve the Foreign Key of Entity without Including it?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity

There is a way to retrieve the Foreign Key of Grade without Including it?

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
       
public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

Now with this current approach if you want to take the CarrierId you need to include the Entity. Such a Foreign Key, it is possible to retrieve it always without this Include?

```
var student = await _context.Student
                       .Include(x => x.Grade)
                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: How do you plan to `Include` without navigation properties?

Comment: Using Convention 1 in EF is not necessary a navigation property

Comment: `.Include(x => x.Grade)` means that you have navigation property. Why it is not shown in question?